# Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference in simple jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am inserting `li` values into a `ul` element on a form.

Just as testing, I am entering 2 values into the `ul`.  Now, once the user clicks submit, I am checking if any of those `li` values are duplicates in another list... if not, then submit the values.  But, I am working on a scenario where if the user enters a few duplicates and non-duplicates in the `ul`.. then I would want the non-duplicates to be taken away from the `ul` element once they are submitted, but keep the duplicates in the list so that the user can see the duplicates.

Here is my code:

```
console.log("Serial Length - " + $("#SerialUL li").length);
var serialUlLength = $("#SerialUL li").length;

// remove serial numbers that have been submitted from the list on the form.

for(i = 0; i < serialUlLength; i++){
    var serialNumber = $("#SerialUL li:eq(" + i + ")").contents().get(0).nodeValue;
    var isInSubmitArray = $.inArray(serialNumber, submitArray);

    if(isInSubmitArray > -1){
        console.log(serialNumber);
        $("#SerialUL li:eq(" + i + ")").remove();
    }
}
```

As I stated above, as of now, I am only entering 2 `li` values into the `ul` for simple testing.  The list that I am comparing against has 0 values in it.. so there shouldn't be any duplicates at this point.  The problem I am experiencing happens for the second `li` element.  I am receiving this console error:

> Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference

I have debugged in the console, but I guess I am staring at this for too long.  Can someone assist in explaining why I am getting this error?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The values I am entering as `li` are `10` and `11`.  Here is what I see in the console based off of the code above in my question:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Code to show `li` being appended to `ul` element

```
// Append TextBox Value to '<ul>' element for user to see once they click button


$("#SerialUL").append("<li class='bullet-serial'>" + serialTxtBoxValue + "<button type='button' class='remove-button'>x</button></li>");
```

Comment: Log out your loop. See what you get. `console.log($("#SerialUL li:eq(" + i + ")").contents().get(0));`

Comment: @daddygames jQueryObject.get() is to get the DOM node

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54769829/edit), then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant html and CSS to create a [mcve] so we do not have to do it

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane it is returning undefined.

Comment: @mplungjan I see the difference and the documentation now. thank you

Comment: Then step up the chain, see if contents() is returning anything.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane it does return something, but the length is `0` whereas the first `li` element had a length of `2`

Comment: Looks like something off with the injected LI. Show some mark-up.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane okay, just did

Answer (score 0):

How about this vastly simpler and easier to debug - assuming a leading serial number and something not a number after

```js
var submitArray=[123,567];
$("#SerialUL li").each(function(_,li) {
  var ser = parseInt(li.textContent.trim()); // add .replace(/[^0-9]/g,"") if needed
  console.log(ser)
  if (submitArray.indexOf(ser) !== -1) {
    console.log("removing",ser)
    li.remove();
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="SerialUL">
  <li>123 <button>X</button></li>
  <li>456 <button>X</button></li>
  <li>123 <button>X</button></li>
  <li>567 <button>X</button></li>
  <li>789 <button>X</button></li>
</ul>
```

More complex version with some useful extras such as delegation

```js
var submitArray = [];

$("#serialTxtBox").on("input", function(e) {
  var val = this.value;
  $("#err").toggle(val && submitArray.indexOf(val)!==-1);
  if (String(val).length == 3 && submitArray.indexOf(val)==-1) {
    submitArray.push(val);
    $("#SerialUL").append("<li class='bullet-serial'>" + val + "<button type='button' class='remove-button'>x</button></li>");
    $(this).val("");
  }
  if ($("#err").is(":visible")) $(this).val("");
})

$("#SerialUL").on("click",".remove-button", function(e) { // delegation
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
  submitArray = [];
  $("#SerialUL li").each(function(_, li) {
    var ser = parseInt(li.textContent.trim()); // add .replace(/[^0-9]/g,"") if needed
    submitArray.push(ser);
  });
})
```

```css
#err { color:red; display:none  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="serialTxtBox" /><span id="err">Already there</span>
<ul id="SerialUL">
</ul>
```

Comment: When I append the `li` element to the `ul`, I am also putting a button inside of the `li` element so that if the user messed up, they're able to click the button and remove the item from the `ul` list.  So, when I get the `textContent` it's also grabbing the text from the button which is `x`.. so the entire textContent is `10x`.  Also, just tried your code and am receiving `li is undefined` after it shows me the first `li` element

Comment: Sorry, I changed your variable name of `li` to `item`.. so that fixed the previous error, but now receiving `Object doesn't support property or method `remove``.. after it logs the first value into the console.. somehow the second value is not getting hit

Comment: Please see update - I assume the serial is a number, If there are other stuff, use a regex

Comment: Okay, that edit removed the `x` but still getting `Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'`...

Comment: Impossible to say since you have not posted your HTML. It works for my guessed HTML as you can see

Comment: Got it to work.. changed to `$(this).remove();` and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are returning element node with `.contenets().get(0).` "nodeValue" always returns null on element node.

Try filtering for text nodes only on `contents()` function:

```
var serialNumber = $("#SerialUL li:eq(" + i + ")").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).get(0).nodeValue;
```

Or use .`textContent` instead `.nodeValue`:

```
var serialNumber = $("#SerialUL li:eq(" + i + ")").contents().get(0).textContent;
```

Comment: `.get(0).text()` should likely be `.get(0).textContent`

Comment: Yes, you are right. As .get() returns original object not jQuery. Fixed!